# Find the Realtek ALC number of my audio card?

Tags: audio

I'm on windows, don't really wanna get into Linux but will if I have to. I need to find the ALC number of my audio card in my laptop. It's for finding a driver for my OSx86, and I need to know the ALC number.

Device Manager lists its hardware ID as 10EC 0233.

Comment: Did you make up the term "ALC number"? I checked a few search engines and none of them seem to know what that is.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz http://www.tonymacx86.com/audio/143757-audio-realtek-alc-applehda-guide.html here is a link to what I'm trying to do. As you can see I need to find the ALC number. I think it's audio codec is what it is but I'm unsure.

Comment: Go to the device manager, select the device, right-click, select Properties. Under Details, select Hardware Ids. Tell us what value(s) you see.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it says 10EC 0233. I did a search, doesn't tell much.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).

Comment: The question says it's looking for a driver for OSx86 but the OP says they're on Windows.  A Windows driver won't work on OSx86, so it isn't clear what the question is asking for, but OSx86 is also off topic.

Answer (score 3):

You have an ALC233. 0x10EC is the vendor ID for Realtek.