# What is my audio ALC MODEL?

Tags: audio

I'd like please to help me determine what is my ALC number and if possible explain to me how to determine it exactly.

I have an ASUS ROG G703GI and the PCI string is

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0295&SUBSYS_10431ED0&REV_1000
```

Comment: It may be `ALC295` (or `ALC0295` if you like). `VEN_10EC` is the Realtek vendor ID and `DEV_0295` seems to be the exact model. [See this similar question](https://superuser.com/q/887711/302907).

Comment: Hello, sorry for my very late reply and thanks for your amazing support. Is there a way to make sure exactly what is the ALC model I have?

Comment: *"Is there a way to make sure exactly what is the ALC model I have?"* - Unfortunately, I am not certain of another way. That said, I understand the answer below lists `ALC1220` as a possible solution, but you tried using `ACL295`? (assuming it's an option for you)

Comment: I tried both in Hackintosh but both didn't work yet. I will try again the full installation tutorial for audio in Hackintosh with a clean install for both ALC1220 and ALC295. Wish me luck :)

Comment: Good luck, then. ; )

Comment: I was able to finally make sure of installed working codec from windows 10 which was  ALC295 as you suggested. Still, I couldn't yet make it work in Hackintosh. I was able actually to make the Hackintosh read my devices but no sound yet

Comment: Take note device id has [hardly](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/sound/pci/hda/patch_realtek.c#L955) the last say when it comes to figuring out which chip family is being used (and in fact, if you want the fully accurate name down to whatever little whim the marketing people and engineers have in their minds, [sometimes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9f720bb9409ea5923361fbd3fdbc505ca36cf012) not even subsystem or other straightforward information may be enough)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the installed codec from windows 10. I opened Realtek HD Audio manager / About section: Codec was ALC295.

Answer (score 2):

Your audio ID string is

```
HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0295&SUBSYS_10431ED0&REV_1000
```

This can be disassembled to the following information:

- Vendor    = `10EC`
- Device    = `0295`
- SubSystem = `10431ED0`
- Revision  = `1000`

All of these values are represented in hexadecimal.

---

- The Vendor ID `10EC` stands for *Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.*.
- The Device ID `0295` is not registered in the [PCI_ID databases](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10ec) so far, but some googling yields [the following](https://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/24364-latest-realtek-audio-codecs/page/11/)

  > "Realtek High Definition Audio" = IntcAzAudModel, HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0295

  This is from this [GigaByte driver file](http://download.gigabyte.asia/FileList/Driver/mb_driver_audio_realtek_alc1220.zip).

**So it's probably an Realtek ALC1220 audio model.**

Comment: Hello, sorry for my very late reply and thanks for your amazing support.
Is there a way to make sure exactly what is the ALC model I have?
I tried ALC1220 driver with no luck.

Comment: Your soundchip seems to be a _Realtek ALC1220 Audio Codec_. Or, more precise, a **Supreme FX S1220A** ([link to ASUS](https://www.asus.com/microsite/mb/ROG-supremefx-gaming-audio/)) which is applied to many ASUS mainboards. This sound-chip is also part of many other mainboards.

Comment: Hello again
if I opened inside my laptop, will the soundchip name or number be written on it ?

Comment: I really don't know. But there is a certain chance that googling the numbers printed on the chips (if there are any) will lead you in the right direction. However, this should be considered the _last_ option.

Comment: I finally found the installed codec from windows 10. I opened Realtek HD Audio manager / About section :  Codec was ALC295. I thought myself it was indeed ALC1220 but the installed working one in windows 10 was ALC295. Thanks very much though for your help