# Cannot change default audio format (Windows 11)

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-11, bitrate, realtek-hd-audio

Microsoft Surface Book 3, 13.5″, Windows 11 Pro. The default sound output device won’t let me change the sample rate and bit depth. The corresponding Control Panel menu is grayed out with *16 bit, 48000 Hz* setting, and cannot be changed.

[Speakers Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkJWF.png)

In the new Settings interface, the menu is working, but it contains only one option: the same 16 / 48.

[System > Sound > Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fdAf.png)

The audio driver is Realtek HD (SST), here’s what it shows:

[Sound Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcH2D.png)

Here are also some details about the driver (version, hardware ID, etc.):

[Sound Driver Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehAA9.png)

The question is: **How to change the bit depth from 16 to 24 bit?**

Please, if you’d be so kind, don’t ask me what I need this for, don’t convince me that I don’t actually want to change the bit depth, and don’t suggest hit-or-miss solutions like deleting the device for Windows to reinstall it automatically, randomly rebooting the device or praying to Santa Claus.

Comment: Have you tried Realtek's own drivers? They often have option MS leaves out - https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software …but I want to know why you think you need 24-bit on a consumer system. Are you actually working in pro audio? If not, then a) it's unlikely you'll be able to tell the difference, & b) upsampling from 16-bit will gain you nothing except 8 empty bits.

Comment: The very ancient dates of drivers on Realtek website bother me, and none of these drivers claims Windows 11 compatibility. In addition, I cannot figure out which ALC model does my Realtek have: for some reason, even the _RealtekAudioDriverIntegration.ps1_ script from TenForums doesn’t reveal it. Before asking here, I’ve downloaded and installed several drivers that apparently seemed to fit, but each of them only made it worse, so I restored the original driver.

Comment: Have you tried https://superuser.com/q/1532739/347380 or https://superuser.com/q/887711/347380 You still haven't said why you need 24-bit. If you don't know *why* you need it, it's unlikely you do need it. It's a pro audio bit-depth, of little practical use in consumer audio.

Comment: I checked these (and many others) links before, and they didn’t help. And yes, I’m an audio engineer working primarily on Mac Pro, but it isn’t always at hand. Now you know why I want 24 bit, but I still don’t know how to get them; it seems an unequal exchange to me.

Comment: OK, but you should have mentioned why you need it in the first place, rather than reject options with no explanation. I'd get a cheapo USB DAC then $£€ 15 - 20 on ebay. Most of them can do 24/48k on standard protocols [idk if Win might need drivers for something like that, Macs don't]. It's always bugged me the Mac Pros can't do 5.1 natively. I can work 5.1 from Cubase/Nuendo to an external DAC, but I can't even strap a multiband comp over a movie to tame the explosions :\\ For my pro work I have pro DACs, for HTPC etc I use eBay boxes. They're "good enough".

Comment: No praying to Santa Claus? I got nothin' then...